# Not showing sub-categories in category tree in Manage Products page

Tags: category, products-management

I am using **magento copy category extension**, this extension copies categories successfully.

But on `Manage Product` page in `Categories tab`, sub-categories of the original category (that i copied) disappears from the category tree. The copied categories are ok. But when i add a sub category manually to the original category, it solves the problem and subcategories appears.

It shows that sub-categories were not disturbed by the module but problem arises from somewhere else.

Any Suggestions?

### Edit

[image: Category page-Fine]
[image: Product Page- Error]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: are copied subcategories visible elsewhere? maybe below the whole list of category? what exactly you are seeing add product page >category tab. ?

Comment: @echoashu Updated Question with screen shots

Comment: did you rebuild the indexes.. after copying and checked whether they are active or not ?

Comment: @echoashu Neither manual nor programmatic re-index works.
used this code after copy but of no help.
'$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
                foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
               
                 $index->reindexAll();
                }'

Comment: Like same i have 2 stores, i have cloned my category tree, but store 2 website category tree not shown on the website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe there is inconsistency data which was caused by custom module.

You can check catalog table catalog_category_entity with help of query

```
SELECT c.entity_id, c.children_count as original_children_count, COUNT(c2.children_count) as `children_count`, c.level as original_level, (LENGTH(c.path)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c.path,'/',''))) as `level`
FROM catalog_category_entity c
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity c2 ON c2.path like CONCAT(c.path,'/%')
GROUP BY c.path
```

and if it will needed (just compare results), then fix with help of following query

```
INSERT catalog_category_entity(`entity_id`,`children_count`, `level`)
SELECT c.entity_id, COUNT(c2.children_count) as `children_count`, (LENGTH(c.path)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c.path,'/',''))) as `level`
FROM catalog_category_entity c
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity c2 ON c2.path like CONCAT(c.path,'/%')
GROUP BY c.path
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `children_count` = VALUES(`children_count`), `level` = VALUES(`level`);
```