# Subcategories are not being displayed in the backend

Tags: admin, category-tree

I have a website named [vintagecarradio](http://vintagecarradio.com/) that runs on Magento. 
It has been great to manage such a large store on this platform. However, everything was fine a while back but from a few days I have observed that the product subcategories are not getting displayed anymore in the back-end. They do not appear in the general category tree and neither they appear when I try to edit a particular product. However, they seem to be at their place and work fine when the website is browsed from the front end. Please help and advise.

Regards
Brad

Comment: check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/not-showing-sub-categories-in-category-tree-in-manage-products-page

Comment: I've encountered this issue a lot aswell. but to be honest very found a solid reason and fix. so i will subscribe to this for sure ;-)

Comment: check here : http://inchoo.net/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/

Answer (score 0):

As answered to my question, i will suggest you to execute the query bellow against your database

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`,`children_count`, `level`)
    SELECT c.entity_id, COUNT(c2.children_count) as `children_count`, (LENGTH(c.path)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c.path,'/',''))) as `level`
    FROM catalog_category_entity c
    LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity c2 ON c2.path like CONCAT(c.path,'/%')
    GROUP BY c.path
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `children_count` = VALUES(`children_count`), `level` = VALUES(`level`)
```

This solved my issue and hope will work for you.
[reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/not-showing-sub-categories-in-category-tree-in-manage-products-page)